# How I run a JSF application?

Tags: eclipse

I have a problem with a Dynamic Web Project on eclipse. The issue is that when I run the aplication, it always throw the error 404. My project doesn't have faces-config.xml or web.xml and I don't know what to do. I indeed have a index.xhtml.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"> 

<h:head></h:head> 
<body> 
    <h1>HELLOOOOOOO</h1>
</body> 
</html>
```

Please help.

Comment: What URL being requested is returning a 404 error? Does your URL explicitly include the 'index.xhtml'?

Comment: the url is /my_project_name/